# Problem with creating and accesing a 4D vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am creating a 4D vector in c++ , but while accessing it I get segmentation fault. This is part of the code I am trying to write.

```
vector<vector<vector<vector <int>>>> glob;

tuple<int,int> f(vector<vector<int>> map, int u, int i,int k,int childEdge){
  if (glob.size()>=u  && glob[u].size()>=i && glob[u][i].size()>=k && glob[u][i][k].size()>= childEdge) return make_tuple(glob[u][i][k][childEdge],k);
```

The segmentation fault happens in the if. Apparently it tries to access a value that does not exist. How do I check for that?

Answer (score 2):

If `glob.size()` is `u`, then valid indices range from `0` to `u-1`. You should be able to fix this by replacing `>=` with `>` in all your checks in the `if` statement.